# Google Drive users do not have permissions to read file

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I would like to create an application where the users could access to all my data in Google Drive.

I have implemented a 2-legged OAuth to obtain all the data from Google Drive with my server app with no user authorization. The server can obtain all the data with the 2-legged OAuth.

The problem arrives when using, for example, the link of a drive document, the users connected to my app cannot access it due to they have no permissions.
I would like to know if it is mandatory give them permissions to access the files or maybe there is another service provided by google to have a comun storage for all the users without get the authorization or permissions for every single user.

I would like to know to if it is posible to use the Drive interface to show the users the documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually three ways to access Google data.

1. Api key used to access public data.
2. Oauth2 used to access private data.  Prompts for user to give permissions to access data and grants a refresh token.
3. Service accounts.  Service accounts are preauthorized. there is no prompt to request a user permission to access the data.

I am not exactly sure what you mean by 2-legged Oauth.  It sounds like you are talking about a service. You can grant the service account access to your personal drive account by sharing one or more folders with it. *Note: I am not sure if you can share the root folder or not.*

When you wish to allow one of your users to access a file you should have the service account add the user as reader of the file then they will have access. this can be done by [inserting permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create).

Note.  I am not a Node.js developer and I am not sure that service accounts are supported by Node.Js you may have to switch to a server sided language I don't know enough about it.

I do have a blog post that explains [service accounts](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/) in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your response, right now I am using Service accounts method.

Comment: Good then you just need to either have the service account download the files and send them to your user.  Or have the service account update the permissions on the file granting the user access.

Comment: Yes I can right now send the files to the user but what I wanted to do is, that the user could modify and edit the file into the interface of drive, I don't know if it is posible without adding permissions manually to every single user.

Comment: Its possible if you want them to be able to edit it on drive they need permissions or you have to set the file to public.  Your going to have to add permissions to every single user with the service account.   It has the power to add permissions.

Comment: Ok! thanks for your support! I will investigate how to give permissions to my users with the service account.